# Обернуть Javascript в Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
function init(){ // Ищем все поля ввода и назначаем обработчик
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper input[type="text"]').forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('keyup', reCount, false);
    });
}

function reCount(){
    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var count = this.value;
    if(/^(?:\D|\s)*$/.test(count)) // Если пусто или не цифра, то выходим
        return;
    var price = parent.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').dataset.price;
    var disc = parent.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').dataset.disc;
    var total = parent.querySelector('td:nth-child(5) strong');

    total.innerHTML = price * count - (price * count * disc); // Вычисляем итоговую цену за этот товар

    totalReCount(); // Запускаем глобальный пересчёт всех "Итого"
}

function totalReCount(){
    var totals = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper tr:not([class="total"]) td:next- strong');
    var cost = 0;

    totals.forEach(function(item){
        cost += +item.innerHTML; // Пробегаемся по каждому "Итого" и прибавляем к итоговой цене
    });

    document.querySelector('.wrapper .total strong').innerHTML = cost; // Выводим общий чек
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Помогите завернуть это в  `$("body").on`, т.к. скрипт присваивает обработчик после загрузки DOM, а у меня есть данные, которые динамически подгружаются на страницу, и они этим скриптом уже не обрабатываются. =(

Comment: @eicto, я ему код написал на чистом JS, а он хочет превратить его в jQuery.  
Печаль-бяда...

Comment: Никакой печали, ваш код не работает как надо, а делегированные события писать на "чистом" js это надо уровнем много повыше быть и то все фичи реализовать очень непросто будет. Вообще не понимаю я этого jquery хейтерства. Зато все меньше понимаю действия w3c, эта мания всюду запихивать string... кто вот мешает в dataset или dragdata ссылки на объекты стандартизовать? И механизм для этого вполне легитимный есть...

Comment: А когда он просил это сделать, ни о каком делегировании речи не было.  
Сказал бы сразу - написал с делегированием и прочими финтами ухом, не впервой.  
P. S. Печаль от того, что все пытаются jQuery везде пихать, даже нативный код в это дерьмо превращать.

Comment: @TheDoctor jQuery создана с единственной целью "write less do more", и не такое оно уж  и дерьмо по сравнению с вашим "нативным" кодом. говнокод, к слову, у вас начинается со второй строчки. (расширение объекта браузера)

Comment: @eicto, возможно в идеале так и задумано, но на практике вышло чуть иначе:  
Каждый школотёнок, решивший что знает `$()` и `el.on()`, знает JS! Но даже этого мало: они даже в нём путаются в этих трёх соснах, слова **замыкания** и **прототип** кажутся им ругательством, как следствие куча сайтов клепается так, что нередко возникает желание позавтракать создателями ресурса...  
Помимо этого, это писать приходится не настолько уж и много, если мозг есть.  
Я встречал особей, которые реально думали, что jQuery - это сам язык, а Vanilla - это что-то другое.  
Библиотека должна помогать, а не...

Comment: А не что? Я встречал некоторых, которые считают, что вызовы биндингов браузера можно считать нативными... А еще я встречал некоторых, которые, кроме ассемблера, ничего не признавали. Ещё наверняка, есть люди, которые не ездят на велосипедах, собранных не ими самими (при этом они в общем-то не гениальные конструкторы, просто считают, что заводское изделие - дерьмо, а их поделка лучше). Есть и другие люди, они берут инструмент и используют его по назначению. jQuery не идеальна, но не вам судить о ее недостатках, повсеместное использование (включая замещение) точно уж не недостаток.

Comment: @eicto, как раз и недостаток.  
Я не против неё, у самого библиотечка и даже не одна.  
Но одно дело помогать, другое - юзать как палочку: одной строчкой писать всё.  
Не в jQuery - подключим плагин, ещё нет плюшки - второй плагин.  
Куча абсолютно ненужного кода, никакого развития в плане разработки, глюки как следствие кучи порой несовместимого кода, т.к. некоторые "плагинописаки" не знают о NameSpace, etc...  
Спорить надоело, позвольте откланяться, правых-то всё-равно нет - это же мнения.  
P. S. "а не..." - просто закончился лимит на символы, прям как сейчас :)

Comment: @eicto, говнокод - понятие относительное. Я не вижу ничего плохого в том, чтобы добавить в NodeList метод forEach. Задумайтесь над тем, почему в Dart он есть https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.NodeList#id_forEach

Comment: @Lucky, модифицирование прототипов в js сродни предоставлению UB-небезопасного интерфейса в сишке. Через год все браузеры предоставляют чуть иную реализацию, а вы ее пропатчили, и на конкретном сайте все работает не так, как ожидается. Или приходит еще один девелопер, так же патчит и вставляет свою функцию на это же место.

Comment: @Etki, это довольно гипотетические примеры. Через год вообще все может поменяться, а по поводу еще одного девелопера, ну что ж. Читать чужой код ему религия не позволит?

Comment: Вообще, мне кажется, эту тему впервые в 2010 году затронул Kangax в своей статье What's wrong with extending the DOM. До этой поры никому и в голову не приходило, что это плохо. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Нашел вот такую интересную статью по теме https://github.com/nbubna/mind-hacking/blob/gh-pages/extending-the-dom.md

Comment: @Lucky ... как-то авторитет не очень... да ещё и связанный с esha.com


кроме того, "Читать чужой код ему религия не позволит" - иногда чужого кода бывает больше чем можно за раз взять и прочитать, тут мы вообще попадаем в поле "глобалс это плохо". 

"Задумайтесь над тем, почему в Dart он есть" наверное Dart это другой язык, другой стандарт итд , его структуры документированы отдельно, разве нет ? (то что он волею судеб компиляется в js и может работать с браузером..


"Вообще, мне кажется, эту тему впервые в 2010 году затронул Kangax", я ещё раз напомню о глобальных переменных.

Comment: TheDoctor, за код спасибо! На предыдущей странице я уже писал благодарность и просьбу по возможности завернуть в jQuery. Любую помощь, которую мне тут оказывают, всегда переписываю под свой проект, т.к. полного функционала в нескольких строчках нельзя выразить. Но этот чистый код, как не извращался, под свои нужды не смог запилить(( Он работает так как надо, но у меня данные подгружаются и после загрузки DOM, а этот код этого не умеет(( К тому-же в моем примере на фиддле был код с применением jquery.